# How do I get my java program running even though it has no errors? What have I done wrong? How can I make the program run?

Tags: java, windows-7-x64

In this program I am supposed to ask the user whether or not they would like to order ONE pizza and if they say yes, they must enter:

`their last name (don't worry about validating)`,

`their choice of pizza type` and

`their choice of pizza size.`

The choices are `veggie, cheese, pepperoni, and supreme.` You can only get a `small, medium, or large.`

Each person can only order one pizza. Only things you need to validate are the initial response, the types of pizza, and the sizes. When I compiled my program I had no errors, but when I tried to run it all it did was show my code. When I say "all it did was show my code" I mean that on the browser I used it showed exactly what I see in Notepad++. I ran it by clicking the "run" drop down button on Notepad++. It gave me options to run it in different browsers. I tried running it in mozilla and chrome with the same results (only showing source code, not running my program). Any advice on how to get my program working??

```
/*This program will keep prompting the user to enter their pizza order, perform 
  the requested calculation, and then output the requested result.
  Written by Hannah Lane*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PizzaOrders
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallpizzas = 0, mediumpizzas = 0, largepizzas = 0, numberoforders = 0;
    double totalordercost = 0.0, pizzacost = 0.0, averagecost = 0.0;
    String custlastname = "", pizzasize = "", pizzatype ="", response = "";

    /*The loop will prompt the user to see if the customer would like to order a pizza. 
      If yes, it will prompt the user for their last name, choice of pizza type, and 
      their choice of pizza size. The two possible responses are yes and no. The dummy 
      value for the loop is no. */

      System.out.print("Do you want to order one pizza?" +
             "Type yes or no (all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
             response = input.next();
             while (!(response.equals("no")))
             {
                /*Validate the user's response. If it is valid, prompt for the required 
                  values, perform the calculation, and output the result. If invalid, 
                  output an error message. */

                if (response.equals("yes"))
                {
                  System.out.println("Please type in your last name (it can only be one word) and then press the ENTER key.");
                  custlastname = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be" +
                                     "pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                  pizzatype = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza size in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must" +
                                     "be small, medium, or large.");

                  pizzasize = input.next();

                  /* Validate the entries for the calculation. The sizes must be small, medium, or large. The types of
                     pizza must be pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme. For division, we must make sure the denominator
                     is not zero. If invalid, output an error message. */

                  if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni") || pizzatype.equals("veggie") || pizzatype.equals("cheese") ||
                      pizzatype.equals("supreme") && pizzasize.equals("small") || pizzasize.equals("medium") ||
                      pizzasize.equals("large") && numberoforders !=0.0) 
                    {
                       if (pizzatype.equals ("pepperoni"))
                       {
                           if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                           {
                             smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if(pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 10.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("veggie"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 10.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 12.25;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 12.25;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;   
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("cheese"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 7.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 7.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("supreme"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 11.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 11.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 16.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 16.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                          averagecost = totalordercost/(double)numberoforders;
                          System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost);
                        }
                    }
                }
                  else
                      System.out.println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be yes or no.");

                  System.out.println("Do you want to order one pizza? Type yes or no" +
                          "(all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
                  response = input.next();
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give us more information so we can help you. What exactly do you mean by "all it did was show my code"? *How* exactly did you try to run it? Have you tried running a smaller program? If the problem is "running any program" then you can use a much *much* smaller program to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us the command you use to execute the program?

Comment: I ran your program. It's giving me a prompt: ```Do you want to order one pizza?Type yes or no (all lower case), then press the ENTER key.```. Seems to be working. How exactly are you running it?

Comment: share command promts screen shot

Comment: Jon, what do you mean when you say I can use a much smaller program? Any tips? Also, I have an older computer so screen shots don't seem to work on it.

Comment: Hannah, if you have a new question, please ask it as a new question, rather than as an additional part to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compiled the program before running?
*You must have JDK installed in your PC*

**Steps to compile and run a java program -** 
1 ) write your java code using a text editor and save the file as classname.java (in your case, the class name is "PizzaOrders" ).

2) open command prompt and navigate to the folder you have saves the previous file. (i.e PizzaOrders.java).

3)run command javac PizzaOrders.java.

4)run command java PizzaOrders.

Comment: He mentioned that he has compiled the program.